# Is the equality correct?

Tags: numerics

[image]

Is the equality above correct where q satisfies |q|<1 ? If it is, how to prove it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Mma.SE! First, take the [tour] so you learn the basic rules of the site. Your question may be put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) because it seems to be [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD), i.e. it's about Maths and not about Wolfram Mathematica programming. Probably you are looking for [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/). If that is NOT the case, and you want help on Mathematica please [edit] your question to make it explicitly about Mathematica programming. Include a [formatted](https://wolfr.am/v57OLJu4) minimum example of the code you are working on.

Comment: You may want to consider $q=0$ as an example. (But the question is off-topic for this site.)

Answer (score 3):

If I am not mistaken, this is not true. Let us specify parameters:

```
Product[(1 - (1/2)^k)/(1 + (1/2)^k), {k, 5 + 1, Infinity}]
```

> `1683/217 EllipticTheta[4, 0, 1/2]`

```
N[%]
```

> `0.93941`